# Adding header parameter to C# browser component

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms, c#-4.0, browser

I am using System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser webBrowser1 in c#. Want to add a request header to every request made from this browser.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this,

webBrowser.Navigate("http://stackoverflow.com", null, null,
                    "Custom Header");

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried this but web page I am embedding inside browser opens lot of javascript connection just like gmail or fb. I want to add header parameter to all those requests too. Navigate() is sending custom header to only initial request.